Why didn’t Emmett find any survivors when he visited the radio station in the valley for the first time?
Marcus hears the song "Beyond the Sea" playing on the radio. Emmett says it has been airing continuously for four months, and he also mentions the location of the radio tower:

Emmett: It's the valley. I tried the radio from our house too, but we
never heard anything until we got up here. Your dad was never gonna
make it work.
Regan: You're nothing like him!

Why didn’t Emmett find any survivors when he visited the radio station in the valley for the first time?
But the second time, he found survivors who helped him at the radio station. Regan transmits the high frequency through the room’s speakers, incapacitating the creature, and impales its exposed head with a rod, killing it.
